# Beamer slides and tufte-handout

Tags: beamer, document-classes, tufte

I have been experimenting with a setup for slides and handouts with one main.tex file that is `\input{}` into a "slides" and a "handout" file (as described in the beamer user guide 21.2.1, or [this example](http://happymutant.com/latex/misce/beamer.php). This setup allows the handout to be typeset using different documentclasses (i.e. report, article - which I am able to produce).

However, I have been trying to use the tufte-handout class, but the compilation comes to a halt, without giving any particular error messages.

I noticed the compilation halted on `amsthm` so I used the `[noamsthm]{beamerarticle}` class option. Then the compilation halted on `beamerbasetheorems.sty`so I used `[notheorems]{beamerarticle}` in the class option, but then it once again halted on `amsthm`.

I then tried to give both in the class options (i.e. `[notheorems,noamsthm]{beamerarticle}`), but this appears to ignore the `[notheorems]{beamerarticle}` option resulting in the same error message as when only giving the `[noamsthm]{beamerarticle}` option.

So, my question is, has anyone successfully used this setup to produce beamer slides and handouts using the tufte-handout class?

Minimal examples provided as requested:

File1 (slides.tex):

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}  
\input{main.tex}
```

File2 (handout.tex):

```
\documentclass{article} % This class works  
%\documentclass{tufte-handout} % Whish to use this documentclass  
\usepackage{beamerarticle}  
\input{main.tex}
```

File3 (main.tex):

```
\usetheme{Singapore}  
\title{Title here}  
\author{Some author}  
\date{}  
\begin{document}  
\maketitle  
\begin{frame}  
\titlepage  
\end{frame}  
\section{One section}  
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{One frame} 
\end{frame}  
Text out of frame. Should print on handout only.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal example that we can actually try.

Comment: Not sure if this is highjacking. If, so I apologize but I have the exact same problem with \documentclass{article} and I don't know enough to modify the above.

Comment: Actually, LaTeX does not hang, I just cannot get the title to show in the article version (OSX 10.4.11)

Comment: @schremmer: Welcome to tex.sx! Yes, actually this _is_ kind of highjacking. You should ask a new question; in that question you can link to this one.

Comment: @schremmer: Just a note to confirm Hendrik's comment, this ought to be reposted as a question for you to get the best chance of it being answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey) includes copying style definitions from tufte-common.def into the main.tex file.

The following works fine:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}  
\usepackage{beamerarticle}  

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{%  
  \gdef\@title{#2}%  
  \begingroup%  
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command  
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents  
    \protected@xdef\thanklesstitle{#2}%  
  \endgroup%  
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%  
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{\thanklesstitle}}% use thankless title  
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{#1}}% use provided plain-text title  
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle}}}{}% set the PDF metadata title  
}  
\makeatother  

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand*{\author}[2][]{%  
  \gdef\@author{#2}%  
  \begingroup%  
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command  
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents  
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%  
  \endgroup%  
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}  
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}% use thankless author  
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}% use provided plain-text author  
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}{}% set the PDF   metadata author  
}  
\makeatother  
\input{main.tex}
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem appears to be related to the `\title` command.  When I compile a document using `\title` then it hangs, and when I compile it without then it works just fine.  There's a bit of a tangled web of definitions and redefinitions going on that is a bit hard to track.  One method that worked for me was to copy out the (re)definition of `\title` from `tufte-common.def` and stick it in after the call to `beamerarticle`.  Thus my main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{%
  \gdef\@title{#2}%
  \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
    \protected@xdef\thanklesstitle{#2}%
  \endgroup%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{\thanklesstitle}}% use thankless title
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{#1}}% use provided plain-text title
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle}}}{}% set the PDF metadata title
}
\makeatother

\input{tufteMain}
```

Of course, that means that the title doesn't get "beamerified", but as this is only for the article version, that doesn't matter.

I tried storing the old definition of `\title` before calling `beamerarticle` and resetting it afterwards, but that didn't work:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\let\tufteTitle=\title
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\let\title=\tufteTitle

\input{tufteMain}
```

still hung.

In general, TeX hangs like that when it enters an infinite loop, so my *guess* is that somehow the definition and redefinition of `\title` mean that it ends up calling itself again and again.  Also, when TeX enters an infinite loop then the logfile contains the last thing that it did okay, so removing stuff that has appeared in the logfile isn't an optimal strategy (you *may* happen on whatever it was that created the loop, but there's no guarantee).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, that solution does not work on my computer (using MikTex 2.7 on Windows XP). The compilation still hangs on `amsthm` even after using your suggested code.

Comment: @Tormod: what happens if you don't use `\title`?  In fact, try your document with none of the titlepage commands (`\author` and so on) since if it hung with `\title` it may well do the same with the others.  I see you've posted your MWE, I'll have a look at those.

Comment: @Tormod: Yup, `\author` seems to have the same problem.  Copying the definition of `\author` from `tufte-common.sty` (or `tufte-common.def`) just as with the title made it work for me.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! That does the trick. I will post a complete solution and credit you.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I ran into this problem recently. In my case, putting the title, author, and date macros *before* `\usepackage{beamerarticle}` fixes the problem.