# Why package enumitem conflicts with Tufte-book and/or beamer

Tags: beamer, package-writing, enumitem, tufte

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer)

I am trying to produce a package, combining `tufte-book` and `beamer`,
in order to produce lecture slides and handout (with explanations)
for students from the same source. I found the useful hints in thread
[Beamer slides and tufte-handout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/beamer-slides-and-tufte-handout).

I attach two sources. The file `mwe.tex` is essentially identical with that I found in that thread. The file `main.tex` contains a simple description:

```
\begin{description}
\item[OneItem] one item
\end{description}
```

It compiles fine. However, when I also add the line

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

then the compilation hangs as described by the conflict of `tufte` and `beamer`.
When I comment out the 3 lines of the description, but keep the `\usepackage` line, the compilation is fine again.

I have found the thread
[Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer)
but the patches described there do not work for me.

Any hints?

The two mentioned files: `mwe.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
            noxcolor,       % needed for cooperating with beamer
            ]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}  % noxcolor needed for tufte
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand{\title}[2][]{%  
  \gdef\@title{#2}%  
  \begingroup%  
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command  
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents  
    \protected@xdef\thanklesstitle{#2}%  
  \endgroup%  
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%  
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{\thanklesstitle}}% use thankless title  
    {\renewcommand{\plaintitle}{#1}}% use provided plain-text title  
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdftitle={\plaintitle}}}{}% set the PDF metadata title  
}  
\makeatother  

\makeatletter  
\renewcommand*{\author}[2][]{%  
  \gdef\@author{#2}%  
  \begingroup%  
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command  
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents  
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%  
  \endgroup%  
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}  
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}% use thankless author  
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}% use provided plain-text author  
  \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}{}% set the PDF   metadata author  
}  
\makeatother  


\input{main.tex}
```

File `main.tex`:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usetheme{Singapore}  
\title{Title here}  
\author{Some author}  
\date{}  
\begin{document}  
\maketitle  
\begin{frame}  
\titlepage  
\end{frame}  
\section{One section}  
\begin{frame}  
\frametitle{One frame} 
\begin{description}
\item[OneItem] one item
\end{description}
\end{frame}  
Text out of frame. Should print on handout only.  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on the list-specification you require rather than trying to make `enumitem` work with `beamer`. Your MWE does not indicate this.

Comment: I patched your MWE but posted the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31505/trouble-combining-enumitem-and-beamer/48470#48470 by mistake. Probably it could be moved but probably any answer should solve both questions and thus make this one a duplicate.